# Is there an easy way to do transparent forms in a VB .NET app?

Tags: vb.net, transparency

I'm writing a simple app that's going to have a tiny form sitting in one corner of the screen, updating itself.

I'd really love for that form to be transparent and to have the transparency be user-configurable.

Is there any easy way to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try using the [Opacity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.opacity.aspx) property of the Form. Here's the relevant snippet from the MSDN page:

```
private Sub CreateMyOpaqueForm()
   ' Create a new form.
   Dim form2 As New Form()
   ' Set the text displayed in the caption.
   form2.Text = "My Form"
   ' Set the opacity to 75%.
   form2.Opacity = 0.75
   ' Size the form to be 300 pixels in height and width.
   form2.Size = New Size(300, 300)
   ' Display the form in the center of the screen.
   form2.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen

   ' Display the form as a modal dialog box.
   form2.ShowDialog()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the `Form.Opacity` property. It should do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Set `Form.Opacity = 0.0` on page load

I set something like what your talking about on an app about a year ago.  Using a `While` loop with a small `Sleep` you can setup a nice fading effect.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what you mean by transparent, but if you use WPF you can set `AllowTransparency = True` on your form and then remove the form's style/border and then set the background to a color that has a zero alpha channel. Then, you can draw on the form all you want and the background will be see-through and the other stuff will be fully visible. Additionally, you could set the background to a low-opacity layer so you can half see through the form.